# Cadena Json a Arraylist

Tags: java, json, java-swing, jtable, jsonobject

quería pedirles su ayuda, lo que pasa es que basandome en estas paginas:

Links con los que me estoy apoyando:

Link1.- https://codejavu.blogspot.com/2013/10/ejemplo-jtable.html?showComment=1561403007739#c4363104628701164366

Link 2.- https://crunchify.com/how-to-read-json-object-from-file-in-java/

quiero convertir una cadena Json a ArrayList para poder continuar con el ejm del primer link que les proporcioné, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, miren este es mi codigo:

```
 JTable miTabla1;
        JScrollPane miBarra;

        miBarra = new JScrollPane();
                miBarra.setBounds(27, 72, 379, 130);


private String[][] obtenerMatriz() {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try{
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));


            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
                String cadenaArchivoJson= jsonObject.toJSONString();


                System.out.println("Cadenita json Archv "+ cadenaArchivoJson);  

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


private void construirTabla(){
        String titulos[]={"Folio Referencia","Folio Evento",
                        "Tipo Mensaje","Clave Cotizacion", 
                        "Razon Social", "Serie","Isin",
                        "Mercado Principal","Tipo Evento",
                        "Indicador","Completo", "Confirmado",
                        "Fecha Exdate","Tipo Evento",
                        "Fecha Registro"};

        String informacion[][]=obtenerMatriz();
        miTabla1 = new JTable(informacion,titulos);
        miBarra.setViewportView(miTabla1);

    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es meter la información del json(Lo que se extrae de la ruta) en un JTable, por el momento lo estoy poniendo como "Código duro" el nombre del archivo json, pero lo quiero hacer es que sea dinámico, es decir, que tome cualquier json sin importar el nombre, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentario Saludos.

Nota: Si hay algo que no me de a entender, con gusto lo pongo.